# Having a select that fetch the options after writing atleast 3 char

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I need to have a select (I was trying to use v-select) that have no options at the beginning but that fetch the options after we write atleast 3 char.
With most select in html, we can write and it filter the options, I want to fetch the options after.

I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you tried "v-select", I guess that you're using vuetify.
If I'm correct, "v-select" is not the vuetify component that you're looking for.
Instead, you're should use "v-autocomplete" (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#usage)

You may also need to add debounce time before launching the rest call